# Html click event not displaying the results (by using JavaScript) on the page

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

After clicking the button the JavaScript displays the result on the new tab, but I want the results to be displayed just below the button.

```
<html>
 <body>
    <input type="button" id="button1" value="Click Here" onclick="print();"/>
 
    <script type="text/javascript"> //script to do some task
    function print()
    {          
          
     document.write('My Text Goes here ');
                           
    }
   </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: using document.write is not a good practice.

Comment: beside it works fine check this fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/wk7cS/](http://jsfiddle.net/wk7cS/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017754/open-in-new-tab-with-dynamic-content and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427479/programmatically-open-new-pages-on-tabs may useful to you

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.write only before the pages complete to load.

If you want to add that text after the page is loaded you have to alter the DOM using some native javascript functions (appendChild, createElement, etc), or you can use jQuery (or other javascript framework) for this. The second is easier because you don't need to concern of browser compatibility.

jQuery eg:

> $("#button1").after("My Text Goes here");

Answer (score 0):

Remove `semicolon` from `onclick functio`n but it works without any problem when writing semicolon  OR not.

```html
 <input type="button" id="button1" value="Click Here" onclick="print()"/>
 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function print()
    {          
          
     document.write('My Text Goes here ');
                           
    }
   </script>
```